# Why must $0≤c_i≤1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

The question states:
[image: Question statement]

The given solution is as follows:
[image: Solution statement]

Why must $0≤c_i≤1$?

Comment: It is so that $x$ stays inside the parallelepied. It will be easy to see if you consider the standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Take a look at this illustration https://www.desmos.com/calculator/idcl5wqmlb.

Comment: @Sonal_sqrt You should consider posting an answer based on your comment text.

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ is a parallelpiped in $\mathbb{R}^n$ formed by the vectors $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$ then (by definition)
$$
P = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n | x=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\ldots+c_nv_n~\text{for some}~c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n\in [0,1]\}.
$$
Hence, if $x\in T(P)$ then there are $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n\in [0,1]$ such that $x=T(c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\ldots+c_nv_n)$.